Is a relation containing only one ordered pair (distinct values) always antisymmetric?
Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and the relation $R$ on $A$ be $\{(1,2)\}$
From the textbook, the condition for a relation to be antisymmetric is that: For any $a,b$ in $R$, if $(a,b)$ belongs to $R$ and $(b,a)$ belongs to $R$, then $a = b$. This will deduce that the relation R is antisymmetric.
So, if my relation only contains one ordered pair ($a \neq b$). It is obvious that $(b, a)$ won't be in the relation. And False will always deduce True. So, that means any relation $R$ with one ordered pair (distinct values) is always antisymmetric. (vacuously true)

Yes. The same goes if you have only one ordered pair which contains the same values.

More directly: if $(x,y)\in {t} \land (y,x)\in {t}$, then $(x,y)=t\land (y,x)=t$, therefore $(x,y)=(y,x)$, therefore $x=y\land y=x$, therefore $x=y$.

Yes, it will be antisymmetric. Since you cannot find $x$ and $y$ such that $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $R$, antisymmetricity is vacuously true. You can use the same reasoning to show it is transitive.
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks! So, for any relation, maybe it will have more than one ordered pair. For any a,b, If aRb but b not R a, this means that the relation is always antisymmetric?

@mendax1234: that is the definition yeah (assuming $a\neq b$).
